# Dropping value in a dataframe in a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with sorted values:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sub_run = pd.DataFrame({'Runoff':[45,10,5,26,30,23,35], 'ind':[3, 10, 25,43,53,60,93]})
```

I would like to start from the **highest value in Runoff** (45), drop all values with which the difference in "ind" is **less than 30** (10, 5), reupdate the DataFrame , then go to **the second highest value** (35): drop the indices with which the difference in "ind" is < 30 , then the **the third highest value** (30) and drop 26 and 23...
I wrote the following code :

```
pre_ind = []

for (idx1, row1) in sub_run.iterrows():
     var = row1.ind
     pre_ind.append(np.array(var))
     for (idx2,row2) in sub_run.iterrows():
         if (row2.ind != var) and (row2.ind not in pre_ind):
            test = abs(row2.ind - var)
            print("test" , test)
            if test <= 30:
                 sub_run = sub_run.drop(sub_run[sub_run.ind == row2.ind].index)
```

I expect to find as an output the values [45,35,30]. However I only find the first one.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you explain the logic independently of your loop (rather in terms of your real goal)? It might be possible to get rid of the loop, which should greatly improve efficiency. Maybe also provide a more complex example.

Comment: I want to get all maximum runoff values that occur in a time difference (ind) higher to 30. So I would like to start with the highest value , drop all other runoff values that occur within an ind difference < 30 then move to the second highest value etc... Hope this makes sense.

Comment: There is no value `20` in the column ind

Comment: More or less, can you provide a more complex example? With the current one, it is easy to perform a single command without iterations. Also, what is the shape/size of your real dataset?

Comment: sub_run = pd.DataFrame({'Runoff':[45,10,5,26,30,23,35],
        'ind':[3, 10, 25,43,53,60,93]}) First loop would start with 45 , drop 10 and 5. Second loop would get 35 , drop nothing. Third loop would be 30 drop 26 because the difference in ind is 10 and also drop 23.

Comment: For clarity, what would be the matching expected output?

Comment: Expected outputs are 45 , 35 and 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
list_pre_max = []
while True:
    
    try:
        max_val = sub_run.Runoff.sort_values(ascending=False).iloc[len(list_pre_max)]
    except:
        break
    max_ind = sub_run.loc[sub_run['Runoff'] == max_val, 'ind'].item()
    list_pre_max.append(max_val)
    dropped_indices = sub_run.loc[(abs(sub_run['ind']-max_ind) <= 30) & (sub_run['ind'] != max_ind) & (~sub_run.Runoff.isin(list_pre_max))].index
    
    sub_run.drop(index=dropped_indices, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
>>>sub_run
        Runoff  ind
0   45  3
4   30  53
6   35  93
```

Comment: Thanks. But this gives as outputs 10 and 5. I initially want to find 45 and 5 because the difference in "ind" is > 30 between them.

Comment: sorry I used a wrong condition. I'll edit it now

Comment: Thanks again. I tried your code on a larger array : sub_run = pd.DataFrame({'Runoff':[45, 20, 10 , 10 , 5],
        'ind':[3, 10, 33 , 65 , 45] }) where I should find 45 and 10. I still find 45, 10 and 5.

Comment: but the diff in ind is more than 33 in all 45, 10, and 5. why should you find only 45, and 10?

Comment: Ideally the first loop would drop 20 and 10. The second loop should drop 5 because 10 is higher to 5 and the difference between 10 and 5 is less than 30.

Comment: I got it, I eddited the solution and now this works

Comment: Thanks again. I updated the DataFrame and still doesn't give me the desired output...

Comment: I edited again. now it works. believe me!

Answer (score 1):

> You should never modify something you are iterating over. This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no effect.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

In your case, the modification of `sub_run` has no effect immediately on the iteration.
Therefore, in the outer loop, after iteration on `45, 3`,
the next row iterated is `35, 93`, followed by `30, 53`, `26, 43`, `23, 60`, `10, 10`, `5, 25`.  For the inner loop, your modification works since you re-enter a new loop through iteration on the outer loop.

Here is my advice code, inspired by bubble sort.

```py
import pandas as pd

sub_run = pd.DataFrame({'Runoff': [45,10,5,26,30,23,35],
                        'ind': [3,10,25,43,53,60,93]})


sub_run = sub_run.sort_values(by=['Runoff'], ascending=False)
highestRow = 0

while highestRow < len(sub_run) - 1:
    cur_run = sub_run
    highestRunoffInd = cur_run.iloc[highestRow].ind
    for i in range(highestRow + 1, len(cur_run)):
        ind = cur_run.iloc[i].ind
        if abs(ind - highestRunoffInd) <= 30:
            sub_run = sub_run.drop(sub_run[sub_run.ind == ind].index)
    highestRow += 1
print(sub_run)
```

Output:

```
   Runoff  ind
0      45    3
6      35   93
4      30   53
```